# Inner join with or condition (SQL server)

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables as below:

```
create table table1 (id int not null, c1 varchar(10))       

create table table2 (id int not null, value varchar(10))

insert into table1 values (10, 'record 1')  
insert into table1 values (20, 'record 2')

insert into table2 values (10, 0)
```

My requirement is ...

> I have to fetch all the records from table1 where the 'value' in table2 is either 0 or no record in table2. For id=20 there is no record in table2, but I still want to show it in the result.

**I don't want to use a LEFT JOIN.** I want to use OR condition in the INNER JOIN.

My current query is ...

```
select a.* 
from table1 a 
inner join table2 b
on a.id = b.id and b.value = 0
```

The result I am looking for is...

10    record1   (will be in result because it's value in table2 is 0)
20    record2   (will be in result because there is no value in table2 for 20)

Comment: What's wrong with `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: Do you have to use a join at all?

Comment: The requirement doesn't make sense. You can't use an `INNER JOIN` and represent a row that doesn't satisfy the join criteria. You're saying you want to get ketchup on your hamburger but you don't want to use ketchup. Could you explain WHY you don't want to use a left join, or why you think it is possible to do this with an inner join?

Comment: "or no record in table2" Then how are you going to inner join?

Comment: Or conditions in a join are something to be avoided at all costs!

Comment: @ChrisMoutray, Yeah, now that you mention it, it sounds like Homework.

Comment: change the inner join to left join and put b.value=1. It still returns rows which i dont want to see. That is the reason that left join doesnt solve my issue.

Comment: Well that's because you probably put `WHERE b.value=1` instead of adding it to the `JOIN` clause (putting it in the `WHERE` makes it an `INNER JOIN`). Why don't you state your actual requirements (what results do you want) instead of telling us how we need to solve those requirements for you? Clearly there is a knowledge gap here about inner vs. outer joins, and we'll be happy to straighten out, if you let us.

Comment: Also, since the `value` column in `table2` is `varchar`, make sure you use `b.value = '1'` and not `b.value = 1` (which leads to a potentially expensive implicit conversion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't use an outer join, you can move the test to the where clause to meet the conditions, which is what you would have done before declarative joins were supported:

```
select a.* from table1 a, table2 b where a.id = b.id or b.value = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Now that we know your reasons for demanding us to not use a left join are superficial and at least somewhat misguided, please try this query:

```
SELECT a.id, a.c1 
FROM dbo.table1 AS a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.table2 AS b
ON a.id = b.id 
AND b.value = 0;
```

If that doesn't get the results you're looking for, then please update the question with the results you're looking for, instead of telling us you must perform a left join without using a left join.

Comment: I am looking for a result ...

Comment: 10   record1   and 20 record 2

Comment: Ok so explain again why this can't be done with a LEFT JOIN, like in this answer?

Comment: The LEFT JOIN query that you sent will return result irrespective of 0 or 1. I want to see the result when the value=0 or no value in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Northwind example.

```
select * from [dbo].[Customers] custs where 
not exists ( select null from dbo.[Orders] innerOrds where innerOrds.CustomerID = custs.CustomerID  )
OR
exists ( select null from dbo.[Orders] innerOrds where innerOrds.CustomerID = custs.CustomerID and innerOrds.EmployeeID = 7 )
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, your requirements are strange a bit, but you can try this without joins at all

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table2 WHERE value<>0 OR value IS NULL)
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/42494/4)**